# all target in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm learning using beautiful Linux tool : make. And there is something I want to understand:

Let's take a look at this simple example:

```
JADE = $(shell find pages/*.jade)
HTML = $(JADE:.jade=.html)

all: $(HTML)

%.html: %.jade
    jade < $< --path $< > $@

clean:
    rm -f $(HTML)

.PHONY: clean
```

When I run `watch make` , I really don't understand much the output string: make: Nothing to do with `all'.

Questions:

1. What does the all action do ?
2. Does the all action do anything with watch tool ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `all` target is really just the default target in the makefile you presented. The first target in the file is the default target, which is built when running `make` without specifying a target.

When make tells you that it has no work to do when building the `all` target, then it means that all the dependencies have been previously built and are up to date (i.e. none of their dependencies have been changed since last building them). In your case it means that the HTML output files are newer than the corresponding Jade input files. Thus there is nothing for make to do.

The `watch` utility just repeatedly runs a command for you to watch how its output changes over time. Watch will just run `make` every so many seconds and show the output. When it is run the first time, it will build everything, and all subsequent invocations of `make` by `watch` will say everything is up to date. So it really does not seem to be all that useful to run `make` within `watch`, unless you have something modifying the files at arbitrary points in time and you want to react by rebuilding them, but that seems to be a somewhat contrived example.

Comment: In my case, the makefile does the work of compile coffee, stylus and jade, so it shouldn't have any problem with this. Thanks for your great answer

Comment: Can I specify my all targets as multiple variables like : `all: $(HTML) $(JS) $(CSS)`

Comment: Yes sure, you can. It would be a more instructive experience for you if you tried these things out first and only asked the things you have tried and did not work out. You will profit more in the long run.